# Invoking a Webservice in C using libxml2

Tags: c, webservice-client, soap-client, libxml2

I am writing a C code to parse a XML file for which I use libxml2 library. The xml is stored in file.  Now, I need to call a WebService from the same C (client)program and then fetch that XML  and parse it.

I am a bit confused and want to know if libxml2 library can do this?
Or do I need some other library to handle the REQUEST/RESPONSE to the webservice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libxml2 can only parse, generate or modify an XML tree, stored in a file or in memory. If you want to do an HTTP(S) request and get a response, you need to use another library, for example libcurl (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Note also that libxml2 doesn't know anything about SOAP, as I assume from your question that you are willing to use a SOAP WebService, so you will have to write some code using libxml2 to effectively parse the response.

Comment: Thank you...!!! :D That helped....I will try to inculcate that into my code now...